# Possible game result combinations in a FIDE tournament report file

Tags: rules, software, fide

I am currently working on a small side project and want to write a chess tournament manager in Haskell. To properly set up the data structures I am wondering what the possible results of a chess game are.

The [TRF (tournament report file) specification](https://www.fide.com/FIDE/handbook/C04Annex2_TRF16.pdf) by FIDE describes the following eight (single player) results:

*Regular Game*

1. Win
2. Draw
3. Loss

*Unrated Results (game lasted more than one move)*

4. Win (unrated)
5. Draw (unrated)
6. Loss (unrated)

*Forfeit Results*

7. Forfeit Win
8. Forfeit Loss

Not considering (pairing allocated) Byes, this would amount to 8x8 = 64 theoretically possible combinations, most of which are probably nonsensical or extremely rare.

However, I think the combination `(Draw, Loss)` exists for example when one player doesn't have sufficient material to end the game and the other one gets disqualified by the arbiter. Maybe even `(Forfeit Loss, Loss)` exists, when player A does not arrive to the game and player B offends the arbiter and thus gets his game counted as a loss.

So which combinations exist additionally to the following obvious ones?

```
{(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 6), (5, 5), (6, 4), (7, 8), (8, 7)}
```

Comment: Can you have a look at https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/12403/what-are-the-possible-results-of-a-game/12410#12410 to see if it covers all the cases you are thinking about?

Comment: (2, 3) and (5, 6) if game is declared lost for one player but his opponent cannot mate.

Answer (score 2):

One additional set of result combinations arises if you are unrated but about to get a rating and you play a rated player. Then, because you are unrated, the game will not be rated for your opponent but, because it forms part of your results which give you a rating, it will be rated for you.

Hence, you can add (1,6), (2,5) and (3,4)

PS I've edited the title of your question because the original was almost identical to this already answered question - [What are the possible results of a game?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/12403/what-are-the-possible-results-of-a-game). However you are asking something different.